# How to display a specific folder from a document set on another page - SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

I have created a new page in my SharePoint site and I would like it to display a specific folder within a document library that already exists on another page in my site.  Is that possible?  If so, how would I go about doing that?

Your help or suggestions would be much appreciated!

Thanks,

-ianw

Comment: Nevermind... I figured out how to do this.  I just added the Document Set to my new page then modified the view to only show the folder I wanted to display.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you found an answer, but for those looking for a solution, modifying the view doesn't allow you to specify a folder, just a document library view. The only true way I've found is to open the page in Sharepoint Designer and modify the actual code of the document web part placed on that page.

You'll find the document web part, look for the query line, and add/modify it to include this:

```
<where>
    <contains>
        <FieldRef Name="FileDir" />
        <Value Type="Lookup">[Name of Folder]</Value>
    </contains>
</where>
```

Make sure to replace **[Name of Folder]** with the name of the directory within your document library for your site that you want to point towards. Also, make sure to change the View of the web part to look for files, not folders.